# How to run a simulation of CAN messages on Python

Tags: python, can-bus

I have am currently learning how to use libraries in python and I have a project in mind, which requires me to use the CAN library https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html . I would like to simulate CAN messages to test and create a platform that can convert them into readable messages. I just can't seem to understand how to get the simulator from the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with `python-can` but if all you want to do is import the module,  here's a snippet that imports the library and sends out a simple message (receiving them is a whole other matter). You might want to keep exploring the docs for ways to capture messages and do stuff with them.

```py
import time
import can

bus = can.interface.Bus(interface='virtual', bustype='socketcan', 
                        channel='vcan0', bitrate=500000)

def producer(bus, id):
    for i in range(10):
        msg = can.Message(arbitration_id=0xc0ffee, 
                          data=[id, i, 0, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1], is_extended_id=False)
        try:
            bus.send(msg)
            print("Message sent on {}".format(bus.channel_info))
            time.sleep(1)
        except can.CanError:
            print("Message NOT sent")

producer(bus, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

A few random ideas (I'm new to this field, please excuse me if some of these have already been solved in different/better ways) :

1. Could Python mock library be used along with capture and replay technology to create a system that customizes the CANbus devices whose behavior needs to be adapted for testing purposes ?
2. What about Wireshark interactors?  If a CANbus dump could be represented as a pcap file, then it could be interpreted.  Common CANbus device decodes could be added to the interactor.